# Git show all reachable commits at distance n from a given commit

Tags: git

Is there a command to show the commit subtree with depth `n` centered on a given commit?

In other words, given the following commit tree

```
A +-> B +-> C +-> D
|     |
|     +-> E +-> F
|
+-> G
```

- `git ??? --depth 1 C` should return `B, C, D`
- `git ??? --depth 2 C` should return `A, B, C, D, E`

Ideally the output should be formatted as the output of `git log --oneline --graph`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must write your own program for this.

This is nontrivial to compute because Git's commit linkage goes only *backwards*.  You've drawn the commits linked together forwards (which actually also has the same difficulty, but solving the problem requires knowing which way the arrows go).  That is, the actual set of links is this:

```
G-> A
F-> E
E-> B
D-> C
C-> B
B-> A
```

If you had any *merge commits* in your graph, the merge commit would have multiple arcs.  For instance, given:

```
...--J
      \
       M   <-- somebranch
      /
...--L
```

merge commit `M` has two outgoing arcs, connecting it to commits `J` and `L` (in that order).

You will need to run `git rev-list --parents`, giving it the starting (ending?) point commits from which you wish to have Git work backwards.  This will emit the hash ID of each *reachable* commit, starting from those starting points, and including the parent hash ID for each commit on the same line.  If you want to use all references as starting points, use `git rev-list --all`; if you want to use all branch names, but no tag names, as starting points, use `git rev-list --branches`; if you want all tag names but no branch names, use `git rev-list --tags`; and so on.  See [the `git rev-list` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) for further details.

(You may want to know which commits are starting-point commits.  If so, you'll need some extra work, such as using `git for-each-ref` to comb through references.  Having done that, you can give `git rev-list` raw hash IDs, rather than using `--branches` or `--tags` or `--all` or whatever.)

Note that branch-and-merge might give you a graph like this:

```
       H-----I
      /       \
...--G         M--N--...
      \       /
       J--K--L
```

so that commit `G` is both three steps back from `M` (along the top), and four steps back from `M` (along the bottom).  It is therefore both 4 and 5 steps back from `N`, and so on.  How you want to handle this is up to you.